# Using MvvmCross for authorization?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

What is the best approach for implementing cross-platform authorization (social, facebook, custom) ? `Xamarin.Auth` has some common library (non cross-platform), but I really like MvvmCross style with plugins and IoC.

Has anyone already implemented such plugin/library? The only problem I see is the mix with logic and UI

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best approach for implementing cross-platform authorization (social, facebook, custom) ?

I guess there isn't one best - but rather the best approach depends on your application and its requirements.

> Has anyone already implemented such plugin/library?

Yes, I know of several people who've implemented twitter, facebook and even Google+ integration - but none who have shared their code back to the community.

> The only problem I see is the mix with logic and UI

There are several plugins which already mix logic and UI - e.g. see the PictureChooser plugin - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser (and Share, WebBrowser, PhoneCall, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the Xamarin / Azure Mobile Services component to do my authorisation (with quite a bit if success).  It's easy to set up and supports Google, Twitter, Facebook and Microsoft.

Comment: I want to use it too. My problem was that the implementation of Xamarin components is not crossplatform, so even it has similar interface, the real components are different. Using custom plugin and partial classes I succeed to minimize platform code implementation, but I thought maybe other already did the abstraction